# Extract name and key from string formatted as array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a quick and easy way to turn something like this:

```
job_details[2]
```

Which is a string, in to two variables, $name and $index such that:

```
$name='job_details'
$index=2
```

Edit: To clarify, I am being given job_details[2] as a string, that's it. I want to extract out the job_details bit into a new variable, and the 2 bit into a new variable. Obviously I can do this with regex but I am wondering if there is a nicer solution.

Comment: There's almost always a way to code for something. What exactly is the purpose? I'm unable to think of a scenario where you'd need this.

Comment: Lookup `key()` and `get_defined_vars()` on php.net. That may get you the results you look for.

Comment: No that's no good. I just need to extract that information from the string to _turn_ it in to an array.

Comment: How is a regex not a nice solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
$name = strtok($input, "[");
$index = strtok("]");
```

Comment: Beautiful, this is exactly what I was after. I knew how to achieve what I wanted in several lines, but this is much much better.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
// Search the string
preg_match_all('/([_\w]*)\[([^]]*)\]/', 'job_title[1], job_details[2]', $matches);

// $matches[1] holds your values
// $matches[2] holds your keys
print_r($matches);

// Combine then into a nice array
$data = array_combine($matches[2], $matches[1]);

print_r($data);
```

This should be the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => job_title[1]
            [1] => job_details[2]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => job_title
            [1] => job_details
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

)
Array
(
    [1] => job_title
    [2] => job_details
)
```

For your reference: [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
        $string = 'job_details[2]';
        $str_arr = explode('[', $string);

        $var_value = $str_arr[0];
        $index_value = $str_arr[1];
        $index_value = trim($str_arr[1], '[]');
        echo $var_value."<br />";

        echo $index_value;
        ?>
```

You can use different special characters in string. It will also work.